# Front-running in Quorum IBFT

Tags: security, quorum, ibft

### Are pending transactions processed sequentially in IBFT?

In a networks based on PoW you would usually pay higher gas price in order to get your transaction mined first. Is there a way to **manipulate pending transactions ordering in IBFT**?

Answer (score 1):

there are three types of front running attacks; displacement, insertion, and suppression and they can be symmetric and asymmetric. front-running is pervasive issue tell the moment, however the impact of the issue will depend mostly on the DApp Design. That said as you already know ethereum uses gas price and nonce for transaction ordering, since the gas price in Quorum is zero you just remain with the nonce. The nonce by itself is not a good property to use to protect against front-running. So, to the extent of my knowledge your alternative is to centralize time sensitive functionalist in off-chain order book or to assume front running is unpreventable and design the DApp in ways it eliminate its effects.

https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices 
https://users.encs.concordia.ca/~clark/papers/2014_weis_pres.pdf